# Django templates, suppress newlines after each template tag in for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

Django template system adds empty lines when displaying a list in for-loop. 
I am a bit confused trying to render this template:

```
<h1>My log</h1>

<textarea>
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
</textarea>
```

I expected:

```
<h1>My log</h1>

<textarea>
    * message line of text 1
    * message 
number 2 on multiple lines
    * message line of text 3
</textarea>
```

But I got:

```
<textarea>

    * message line of text 1

    * message 
number 2 on multiple lines

    * message line of text 3

</textarea>
```

Is there some way to suppress empty lines and get desired result?

Comment: Originally, I used for loop in template to iterate loglines. I wanted to show log messages in textarea.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you're looking for the `{% spaceless %}` tags:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

```
<textarea>
{% spaceless %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
</textarea>
```

But note that only space between tags is removed so you may need:

```
<textarea>
{% spaceless %}
    {% for item in items %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
</textarea>
```

In fact the following might actually do it for you:

```
<textarea>
    {% for item in items %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
</textarea>
```

If your `item` elements actually contain line breaks then you will need to strip them in some way before hand, either using a filter or in a model method or something.

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution was found:

```
<textarea>
{% for item in items %}   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}</textarea>
```

Comment: Works much better than any other solution found! Thanks